# how to undo the actions of "make install"?

Tags: php, gcc

Is there a way to undo the actions of `sudo make install`?   That is, remove the files that were copied to the `/usr/local/bin` folder?

I built PHP from source using the following commands:

```
cd /home/steve/php-src
./buildconf
./configure
./sudo make install
```

I assume `make install` is the command that copies the compiled code to the system wide /usr folder. I want to remove the PHP repo and all the compiled objects that were compiled from that repo and copied to system wide folders.

Comment: There's nothing that does this automatically. You could add a rule in the Makefile to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make install` is not a constant command that magically install a C project. It follows a spec. file that contains instructions to how `make` should behave that's called a "**Makefile**".

In order to undo what `make install` did, you must read the **Makefile** that's located under the project's root directory. see what `install` target does and create (if doesn't exist) a target (eg. `uninstall`) that reverses all that `install` does. (eg. remove installed file, detach Kernel hook, ...etc.).